# How to trigger function call after Subscription task is executed in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working on an Angular 4 application that has a service that enables users to upload images. I want my component to be able to be notified whenever this uploading has succeeded. How is that done?

To give an example, this is my function that returns a Subscription object in my `service.ts` file:

```js
uploadImage(new_image:File) {
  this.uploading = true;
  let url = '/products/photo/';
  let newImagePayload = new FormData();

  newImagePayload.append('photo', new_image, new_image.name);

  return this.queryService.postQueryFormData(url, newImagePayload)
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.uploading = false;
      this.image_location = result['photo'];
    });
}
```

In my component, this function is called:

```
let my_subscription = this.cardService.uploadImage(newImage)
   \\ I want to call this.randomfunction() whenever my uploading is finished.
```

How is this done? I expected that I could do something as follows:

```
my_subscription.subscribe()
```

But this is apparently not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `subscribe`, because you are receiving back a `Subscription` from calling the `uploadImage` method. I suggest you call the `subscribe` method inside your component and return an `Observable` instead. You can use the `do` operator instead to invoke the action that you want to and return an `Observable`. The code will look as such:

```
uploadImage(new_image: File) {
    this.uploading = true;
    let url = '/products/photo/';
    let newImagePayload = new FormData();

    newImagePayload.append('photo', new_image, new_image.name);

    return this.queryService.postQueryFormData(url, newImagePayload).do(result => {
        this.uploading = false;
        this.image_location = result['photo'];
    });
}
```

Then inside your component you can call the `subscribe` method.